# Regex for only positive decimals from 0 to 1 upto 2 decimal digits only that works without sign in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I basically want a regex for alpha in RGBA which is always a positive number between 0 & 1. However, I want it to only be upto 2 digits like `0.53` & not more than that like `0.536`.

#### Allowed

> Anything between 0 to 1 but only upto 2 decimal places

```
0
0.0
0.00
0.1
0.12
0.34
1
1.0
1.00
```

#### Not Allowed

> Anything outside of 0 to 1 & if its between 0 to 1 then it should be less than or equal to 2 decimal places only & even signs not allowed

```
0.123
90
3
-1
+1
```

I noticed other similar questions but they allow signs or they allow more than 2 decimal places.

Currently, I have a regex like `/^(0+\.?|0*\.\d+|0*1(\.0*)?)$/` which allows for more than 2 decimal places. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
^(?:0(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|1(?:\.00?)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkmvln/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `0`: Match `0`
  - `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?`: Match *optional* dot followed by 1 or 2 digits
  - `|`: OR
  - `1`: Match `1`
  - `(?:\.00?)?`: Match *optional* 1 or 2 zeroes after dot
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, try:

```
^(?!1..?[1-9])[01](?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zVjQBj/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `1..?` - A literal "1" followed by any character other than newline and an optional one.
  - `[1-9]`- Match a digit ranging from 1-9.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `[01]` - Match a zero or one.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\.\d\d?` - Match a literal dot, a single digit and an optional one.
  - `)?` - Close non-capturing group and make it optional.
- `$` - End string anchor.